# Boot Camp makes unbootable USB drive

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, startup, bootable-disk

I used Boot Camp Assistant to create a Windows 10 install disk. However, the disk is not bootable. I am confused as to why Boot Camp Assistant would make an install disk not bootable. Can someone please help me? I am looking for someone to either a) explain how to recreate the install drive in a way that will make it bootable or b) explain how to force the drive to become bootable.

Here is the information:

[image: Disk Utility Image]

[image: Disk Utility Information]

[image: Terminal information]

Comment: Please add your Mac model (including year) and your current system version!

Comment: Please note I used a MacBook Pro (mid-2014) to make this disk for a Mac Pro (2009) with 5,1 firmware. Could this switching of computers have been a problem?

Comment: If your 2009 Mac Pro has a Optical Super Drive, why did you not try using a DVD to install Windows 10? No 2009 model Mac is capable of booting and installing windows from a USB drive. Apple did not add the USB install option until the 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Mac Pro (MacPro4,1) officially neither supports Windows 10  nor booting from USB thumb drives.

The only Mac Pro model supporting Windows 10 installed with Boot Camp Assistant [according to Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990#models) is the Mac Pro (Late 2013).

Comment: Even if I when I created the drive I added my model ID to Boot Camp Assistant's Info.plist?

Comment: @NoahL I assume some drivers are missing.